# How to concatenate arrays with space?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I don't get it why my arrays don't concatenate,its just that when I concatenate my arrays with any other character, it doesn't show the content of the tempString. But when I remove the special characters, it produces the output.

E.G
When there is no special character, the output is
//ThisisaSingleLineComment
But when I use other special characters, there is no output at all

The Codes I used are the ff.:

```
tempString=tempString+newTokens[ctr];

tempString+=newTokens[ctr];
```

I even used string builder with this code, still there is no output.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
sb.append(newTokens[ctr]);
sb.append(whiteSpace);
```

My output should look like this
// This is a Single Line Comment

Since each and every one of those are assigned in an array that I want to combine to form a single string / queue(stack) value.

Comment: What have you initialized tempString with and what is there in newTokens array, in short your input to the code.

Comment: my tempString was initialized as a space / tempString = "   ";

the contents of my newTokens array is this

newTokens={"//","This","is","a","single","line","comment"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code block while using tempString var should be like below

```
String tempString = newTokens[0];
```

Above statement is to simply to initialize an tempString var against first token received.

For any new token the concatenation should look like this. Or simply token at index 1 till last index of the array.

```
for(int ctr = 1; ctr < newTokens.length; ctr++) {
    tempString = tempString + "\b" + newTokens[ctr];
}
```

You are missing adding a whitespace character in your code. \b is escape character for a blank space or a single whitespace.

You can also use below statement

```
tempString = tempString + " " + newTokens[ctr]
```

I would suggest you put your whole method block for StringBuilder part.

I am not sure of the input or array value you are running your code with.

Typically you will have to run this inside a loop to generate whole string with the StringBuilder.

Sample code for StringBuilder would look like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);

for(int ctr = 0; ctr < newTokens.length; ctr++) { 
    sb.append(newTokens[ctr]);
    sb.append(whiteSpace);
}
```

Your code which is below is incorrect for concatenation.

```
tempString=tempString+newTokens[ctr];

tempString+=newTokens[ctr];
```

Both the statements what it does is it concatenates to last updated value of tempString.

For example, you first initialized tempString with " " a blank space.

First iteration would make the string value as " //". Now the tempString is not simply a whitespace character. You will have to add a new whitespace character separately as I showed in the above examples

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem, might I ask why does it work with the

tempString = tempString + " " + newTokens[ctr] ;

but not with tempString = tempString  + newTokens[ctr] + " " ;  ?

I mean, they are like the same anyway, is there a difference between the two?. It just that I used the later code that is almost the same as the one you gave.

Comment: Basically with tempString = tempString + newTokens[ctr] + " " ; you are adding a whitespace later and not in between your previous tempString and newToken. You need to place whitespace in between last tempString and newToken. When talking about String concatenation it is simply like this A + B is AB and B + A is BA.

Answer (score 4):

Why not using **[String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)**

```
String[] newTokens ={"This","is","a","Single","Line","Comment"};
System.out.println(String.join(" ",newTokens));
```

And, output is

```
This is a Single Line Comment
```

Comment: Yeah String join is a cleaner way to add a particular delimiter in between and array or a List. But what the OP is missing is clear understanding of how concatenation works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `StringJoiner`:

```
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
    for(String string : myList){
        joiner.add(string);
    }
    System.out.println( joiner.toString() );
```

Comment: nice!! atleast I got to know 2 new ways for string concatenation String.join and StringJoiner, both introduced with Java 8

Comment: Me too, although I used the simple + thing concatenation so that it would be easier to read, since it turns out im putting the special character in a wrong place to concatenate. But the String Join by far is the easiest implementation it seems with less less declaration.

Comment: @JoshuaCariño remember that string concatenation in very inefficent. You should try to avoid it.